# Android custom loader (Integer arraylist) does not refresh UI

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I was trying out a custom loader with integer array Have a service in background to add values to the array. As the service adds the entry to the arraylist. I am trying to refresh the refresh the UI listview. Using Broadcast receiver as content observer.

Problem is deliverResult is getting called but it does not refresh UI with new values.

The Main Activity with Listview implements Loadercallbacks.  Thanks a lot everyone..

```html
package loaders.com.myapplication;

import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by k.sekar on 1/7/2015.
 */
class testLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Integer>>{

    public static List<Integer> intlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    private testService mService;

    public  final String BROADCAST_ADDED = "ADDED";





    private Context mContext;

    private Receiver mReceiver;



   public testLoader(Context context)
    {
       super(context);

      

        Intent serviceMedia = new Intent(getContext(), testService.class);
        getContext().startService(serviceMedia);



        if(intlist == null)
        {
            intlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }


        intlist.add(10);
        intlist.add(20);
        intlist.add(30);
        intlist.add(40);

        if(mReceiver == null)
        {
            mReceiver = new Receiver(this);
        }

    }

 


    public  class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

         final testLoader mLoader;

        public Receiver(testLoader loader)
        {
            mLoader = loader;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String message = intent.getAction();

            if(message.compareTo("ADDED") == 0)
            {            
                  mLoader.onContentChanged();
              


            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> loadInBackground() {
      //    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ADDED);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(mReceiver,filter);



      //  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mLoader.getContext()).registerReceiver(this, filter);
        return intlist;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {

        if(intlist != null)
        {
            deliverResult(intlist);
        }



        if(mRefreshData == true)
        {
            mRefreshData = false;
            forceLoad();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading()
    {

        cancelLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset()
    {
        super.onReset();

        onStopLoading();

        intlist = null;


        if(intlist != null)
        {
            intlist = null;
        }

        if(mReceiver != null)
        {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            mReceiver = null;
        }


    }



    @Override
    public void cancelLoadInBackground(){

        super.cancelLoadInBackground();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCanceled(List<Integer> data)
    {
        //  mContext.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
         super.onCanceled(data);

         data = null;

    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(List<Integer> data)
    {
        if(isReset())
        {
            data = null;
            return;
        }

        List<Integer> oldData = intlist;
        intlist = data;

        if (isStarted()) {
            

            super.deliverResult(data);
        }

        if(oldData != null && oldData != intlist)
        {
            oldData = null;
        }

    }

   





}
```

Code snippet of activity

```html
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Integer>> {

     ListView mListView;

     ArrayAdapter<Integer> mAdapter;


    public static final String BROADCAST_REFRESH = "REFRESH";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mListView = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listnumbers);

        mListView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);

        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);

    }

    protected void onStop()
    {
          super.onStop();       
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<List<Integer>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        if(id == 1)
        {
            return new IntLoader(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Integer>> loader, List<Integer> data) {

      
        if (mAdapter == null)
        {
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,R.layout.list_element, data);
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
         
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Integer>> loader) {

        mListView.setAdapter(null);
     
    }








}
```

Answer (score 0):

In activity class, try this.

```
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Integer>> loader) {
    mListView.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: It did not resolve the issue. onLoaderReset is called to remove the reference to the data. please check this http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/android-loaders-we-meet-at-last/

Comment: Ok. Try same in onLoadFinished() as well. According to the documentation you need to call deliverResult() from the process's main thred.read more here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html#deliverResult(D)

Answer (score 0):

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(CATEGORY_LOADER, null, yourActivity.this);
```

This is worked for me. here `CATEGORY_LOADER` has a integer value `1` and `null` is for extra arguments.